# How to compare a string in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like the below tables

Table 1 :

```
P_name
Mohan
Ram
```

Table 2 :

```
R_name
Mohan,Manasa
Ajay
Ram,Raju
```

script :

```
select t.name,tt.name from  table1 t
INNER JOIN table2  tt
ON t.name LIKE '%' + tt.name + '%'
```

I need to compare the table 1 data with table 2 data and get the result set

Output :

```
P_name R_name
Mohan  Manasa
Ram    Raju
```

Comment: Hi Mohan, you should stop storing CSV data in your SQL tables.  The best answer here in fact might be to not answer, but let you improve your database design.

Comment: Ok I agree but the requirement is like that and below answer served my purpose@TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you stored the data as `CSV` format store only one data in single row & do the `JOIN` :

For instance i would do :

```
SELECT t.P_name, substring(tt.r_name, charindex(',', tt.r_name + ',')+1, len(tt.r_name))
FROM table1 t INNER JOIN 
     table2 tt
     ON tt.r_name LIKE '%' + t.P_name + '%';
```